# SoapUI, Maven, TestRails connection

Tags: java, maven, soapui, pom.xml, testrail

I am attempting to POST test results to TestRails.

Using test suites and test cases, the tests in question were created using SoapUI.  What I currently have will POST directly from SoapUI to TestRails.  The company I work for wants to initiate the SoapUI tests using Maven, which is possible with a SoapUI plug-in for the Maven pom file.  This part of the process works perfectly.

However, POSTing to the TestRails project only works if I initiate the tests via the SoapUI application.  When I run the same tests via Maven, all the test steps complete and are visible in the stack trace, but none of the test case results are sent to TestRails.

What I have done is placed a plug-in in the pom file, which is supposed to connect Maven to TestRails and allow the transfer of the test results, but while there are no errors in the program, no POST is done.

Here's how I have it coded in my pom file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId> 
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <settingsFile>${projectDir}\soapui-settings.xml</settingsFile>
                <iface>mobileAdsService</iface>
                <exportwAll>true</exportwAll>
                <printReport>true</printReport>
                <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <outputFolder>${projectDir}\TestResults</outputFolder>
                <projectFile>${basedir}\Irdeto-v1.xml</projectFile>
                <saveAfterRun>true</saveAfterRun>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
                </dependency>
                ***<dependency>
                    <groupId>com.codepine.api</groupId>
                    <artifactId>testrail-api-java-client</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>***
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                  <version>2.0.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                    <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>soapui-tests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>                        
                </execution>
            </executions>   
        </plugin>
```

Comment: This was not a problem with either Maven or TestRails.  After further analysis it was discovered that there is a bug in SoapUI (non-licensed version) in which the program sometimes sends a "GET" when it should be sending a "POST" and thus eliminated the JSON which updated the TestRails program.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been due to a bug in the non-licensed version of SoapUI.